# what is the normal Kafka offset lag? why minimum is 1 (not 0)?

Tags: apache-kafka

i've got configuration with 3 Kafka brokers:

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --topic logs --zookeeper=localhost:2181
Topic:logs  PartitionCount:8    ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:
    Topic: logs Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,2,0 Isr: 0,1,2
    Topic: logs Partition: 1    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,0,1 Isr: 0,1,2
    Topic: logs Partition: 2    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0,1,2 Isr: 0,1,2
    Topic: logs Partition: 3    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,0,2 Isr: 0,1,2
    Topic: logs Partition: 4    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,1,0 Isr: 0,1,2
    Topic: logs Partition: 5    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0,2,1 Isr: 0,1,2
    Topic: logs Partition: 6    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,2,0 Isr: 0,1,2
    Topic: logs Partition: 7    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,0,1 Isr: 0,1,2
```

i noticed that all the time minimum offset lag value is 1.

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-offset-checker.sh --group logreaders --topic logs --zookeeper=localhost:2181
Group           Topic                          Pid Offset          logSize         Lag             Owner
logreaders      logs                           0   255851          255852          1               none
logreaders      logs                           1   254514          254515          1               none
logreaders      logs                           2   252885          252888          3               none
logreaders      logs                           3   255904          255905          1               none
logreaders      logs                           4   253897          253898          1               none
logreaders      logs                           5   253517          253519          2               none
logreaders      logs                           6   255098          255099          1               none
logreaders      logs                           7   255412          255414          2               none
```

I expected that minimum offset lag should be - 0, so i'm trying to figure out is it normal to have this. It does not look like i'm losing messages, but that confuses me.

Kafka version is 0.8.2.1

Answer (score 0):

That was Python kafka client issue.

I created [issue](https://github.com/Parsely/pykafka/issues/289) on github

Answer (score -2):

This issue is related to your **KAFKA PERFORMANCE TUNING**. Its obvious that your consumer is not able to catch-up with Producer.
This can be achieved by tuning the consumer configurations. [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/08/configuration.html) has provided very good [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/08/configuration.html) on this, please refer the same and tune your Consumer.
Please let me know if you have any doubt in Consumer tuning.

Comment: The problem is that i have this even if producer is not generate any messages, so if i stop producer i still have lag - 1 minimum. Not 0.

Comment: If a consumer is not able to catch up with producer one would expect to se an increasing lag.